# Using Excel to work with large amounts of output data: is an Excel-database interaction the right solution for the problem?

Tags: python, database, excel

I have a situation where various analysis programs output large amounts of data, but I may only need to manipulate or access certain parts of the data in a particular Excel workbook.

The numbers might often change as well as newer analyses are run, and I'd like these changes to be reflected in Excel in as automated a manner as possible. Another important consideration is that I'm using Python to process some of the data too, so putting the data somewhere where it's easy for Python and Excel to access would be very beneficial.

I know only a little about databases, but I'm wondering if using one would be a good solution for what my needs - Excel has database interaction capability as far as I'm aware, as does Python. The devil is in the details of course, so I need some help figuring out what system I'd actually set up.

From what I've currently read (in the last hour), here's what I've come up with so far simple plan:

1) Set up an SQLite managed database. Why SQLite? Well, I don't need a database that can manage large volumes of concurrent accesses, but I do need something that is simple to set up, easy to maintain and good enough for use by 3-4 people at most. I can also use the SQLite Administrator to help design the database files.

2 a) Use ODBC/ADO.NET (I have  yet to figure out the difference between the two) to help Excel access the database. This is going to be the trickiest part, I think.

2 b) Python already has the built in sqlite3 module, so no worries with the interface there. I can use it to set up the output data into an SQLite managed database as well!

Putting down some concrete questions:

1) Is a server-less database a good solution for managing my data given my access requirements? If not, I'd appreciate alternative suggestions. Suggested reading? Things worth looking at?

2) Excel-SQLite interaction: I could do with some help flushing out the details there...ODBC or ADO.NET? Pointers to some good tutorials? etc.

3) Last, but not least, and definitely of concern: will it be easy enough to teach a non-programmer how to setup spreadsheets using queries to the database (assuming they're willing to put in *some* time with familiarization, but not very much)?

I think that about covers it for now, thank you for your time!

Comment: How do these "various analysis programs" output the data?  Is this data stored somewhere when they output it?  How are you currently using python to process some of the data?

Comment: From reading http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html it doesn't really sound like SQLite is what you need, considering you want to use it from Excel (an external application) as well as from Python. I may be wrong here, but isn't SQLite usually embedded within an existing program you're writing, in lieu of connecting to a real database? Unless your python program(s) is(are) a server of some kind, I'd suggest just biting the bullet and installing mysql or SQL Server Express here.

Comment: @Gerrat: They output csv based files, easy enough to access in Python. Python may need to do some calculations with the results, or set up an Excel sheet using the results, etc.

Comment: Roughly how much data is 'large amounts'? That could be anything from 10 MB to 10 TB. And how often is it updated? Weekly, daily, twice a second?

Comment: @Thomas K: Let's say at worst: 10 gigs. How often is it updated? At most daily.

Comment: That's probably within the abilities of SQLite, although it will probably take a while to build the database from the CSV file.

Comment: @Thomas K: The entire database will probably not be built in one go, but in stages, so that's quite alright.

Comment: Some may will want my head for saying this... but getting in touch with a database for the first time (as it seems to be the case here) IMO is far easier starting with MS Access. And is very, very, veeeeery easy to integrate Access and Excel.

Comment: You're absolutely right, Tiago!   ....off with your head ;)

Answer (score 0):

Although you could certainly use a database to do what you're asking, I'm not sure you really want to add that complexity.  I don't see much benefit of adding a database to your mix.  ...if you were pulling data from a database as well, then it'd make more sense to add some tables for this & use it.

From what I currently understand of your requirements, since you're using python anyway, you could do your preprocessing in python, then just dump out the processed/augmented values into other csv files for Excel to import.  For a more automated solution, you could even write the results directly to the spreadsheets from Python using something like [xlwt](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt).